# XML XSLT add namespace of xmlns to attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, soap

I have a soap message that doesn't appear to have the correct attributes declared and throws an **Exception**: System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in the XML document.' and **Inner Exception**: InvalidOperationException: Namespace prefix 'xsd' is not defined.

I'm trying to use XSLT to transform the SOAP message to parse it and while it looks good on the surface it's not producing what I expect. I've checked online for a couple days but without any luck. This is the resulting XSLT I have that parses the XML but does not add an "xmlns:xsd" and instead produces "xp_0:xsd".

```
<xsl:template match="//*[contains(name(),'sys:FaultDetails')]">     
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="xsd" namespace="xmlns">
            <xsl:text>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="xsi" namespace="xmlns">
            <xsl:text>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This is what I'm expecting:
<sys:FaultDetails xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

But this is what I'm getting:
<sys:FaultDetails xp_0:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"                     xp_0:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing an example input, your current XSLT and the expected output.

Comment: This feels like an X/Y problem right out the gate. You need to determine the cause of the original exception. You've decided to "fix" it with XSLT, but you really need to *\*fix\** it at the source.

Comment: Do note that a namespace declaration is not an attribute and cannot be created using the `xsl:attribute` instruction.

Comment: Usually invalid XML will be rejected by parsers - it feels quite strange that you actually able to apply XSLT to such text... Seeing [mre] in the question would definitely help.

Comment: The InvalidOperationException ***is*** the parser rejecting invalid XML. That's why this is an X/Y problem.

Comment: @madreflection "But this is what I'm getting:" is the strange part for me - it sounds like OP managed to apply XSLT to XML they claim is invalid... (I agree that fixing source that generates invalid XML is the right solution... and question is X/Y problem... still would love to see MRE from OP as I don't get how it could worked)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: You make a good point. The parsing done by the XSLT engine might be a little looser. Yes, an MRE is necessary here.

Comment: @madreflection Your assumption is wrong. Why not let OP clarify; these speculations are unproductive.

Comment: Not an assumption, just a guess, which you seem perfectly fine with. Frankly, I don't expect OP to follow up on this. 34 minutes without any responses to comments, let alone edits to clarify or add details. It'll die on the vine.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick replies, as you might be aware I'm new to SoF and thought I put enough information and wasn't expecting such an influx of responses so quickly. I'm working on an MRE but it has some code I can't include like the WSDL code.

Comment: @madreflection I meant your assumption that "the parsing done by the XSLT engine might be a little looser."

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the comments to your question, your description is rather confusing. I am guessing you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="sys:FaultDetails">     
    <sys:FaultDetails xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </sys:FaultDetails>
</xsl:template>
```

But without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this cannot be more than just a guess.